# Unset an array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Is it possible to use the $unset operator on array field and remove an element that matches a query. For example i'm trying to remove 35 from field "files" array.

```
{
  _id : 1,
  files : [1,12,35,223]
}
// Ive tried this but it does not work
db.col.update({_id : 1}, {$unset : { files : 35}})
// or this does not work
db.col.update({_id : 1}, {$unset : { "files.35" : 1}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [$pull operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/)? As in:

```
db.col.update({_id: 1}, {$pull: {files: 35}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) instead:

`db.col.update({ _id : 1 }, {$pull: { files : 35 } })`